# androidstudio java errors causing app to crash

Tags: java, android

So I recently started to program a music player for a project that I'm working on in Android Studio. Everything went good until now. When I try to open it, the app asks for the permissions that it's supposed to ask, but then it crashes. I copied the error info so it would be way easier for you to help me solve the problem.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:103)
        at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:57)
```

MainActivity.java:103 -

```
    if(!isMusicPlayerInit){
        final ListView ListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final TextAdapter textAdapter = new TextAdapter();
        musicFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
        fillMusicList();
        textAdapter.setData(musicFilesList);
        ListView.setAdapter(textAdapter);        <-----this is the 103rd line

        isMusicPlayerInit = true;
    }
```

MainActivity.java:57 -

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(arePermissionsDenied()){
        ((ActivityManager) (this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))).clearApplicationUserData();
        recreate();
    }else{
        onResume();    <----this is the 57th line
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not name a `ListView` `ListView` as it will shadow the class. About the error: it seems that `R.id.listView` does not exist yet, maybe this was called before `setContentView` or you are inflating the incorrect layout.

Comment: @CoderCharmander Thank you, I noticed what I did wrong. I do still have an error at the 57th line and it says:

 `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:57)`

Comment: It's just the call stack.

Comment: I'm going to be honest I don't know what that means as I'm kinda new to programming in Android studio, but the app keeps crashing. I'm sorry if I make stupid questions

Comment: If it's still crashing with the same error message, then it's still null. Can you send more code, especially near `setContentView` and `onCreate`?

Comment: Yes, of course. 

Here is the class that contains `setContentView` as well as `onCreate`:


`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
`
Also can you move this discussion to chat? I don't have enough rep to do so

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216646/android-error-troubleshooting

Comment: @CoderCharmander I need 20 rep to chat, whic I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

change this code :

```
 if(!isMusicPlayerInit){
        final ListView ListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final TextAdapter textAdapter = new TextAdapter();
        musicFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
        fillMusicList();
        textAdapter.setData(musicFilesList);
        ListView.setAdapter(textAdapter);        <-----this is the 103rd line

        isMusicPlayerInit = true;
    }
```

To:

```
 if(!isMusicPlayerInit){
        final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);//here changed ListView ==>listView
        final TextAdapter textAdapter = new TextAdapter();
        musicFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
        fillMusicList();
        textAdapter.setData(musicFilesList);
        listView .setAdapter(textAdapter);        //here changed ListView ==>listView     
        isMusicPlayerInit = true;
    }
```

should be listView or any other name not
ListView ListView

Comment: Thank you fo the answer but I'm still having a problem running the app on an emulator as well as on my physical device. The only error I'm getting now is this:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:108)`

108th line is this: `listView.setAdapter(textAdapter);`